# Laravel schema builder add column at start of table

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

When using the laravel schema builder to add a column to a table, by default it gets added at the end of the table. If you use `->after('column')` then you can specify which column is should come after. Is there a way to define that you want to add the column at the beginning of the table?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're talking about migrations, you want to use the `first()` method:

> ->first() -   Place the column "first" in the table (MySQL Only)
>
> ->after('column') -   Place the column "after" another column (MySQL Only)

https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/migrations#column-modifiers

Comment: So is this is only available in Laravel 5.3+?

Comment: I'm not sure about <5.2, but 5.2 has it too: https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/migrations#creating-columns